# Set select index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

So I'm trying set a select index based on a value inside of some objects.  As I cycle through the objects, in console I can see that the colorID is being updated and correct, just that the select index never changes from the option that was last selected.  What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<select 
         ng-model="colorModel" 
         ng-change="updateColor(colorModel.id)" 
         ng-options="i.label for i in colorOptions">
</select>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.colorOptions = [
        {value: 'red', label: 'Red', id: 0},
        {value: 'green', label: 'Green', id: 1},
        {value: 'blue', label: 'Blue', id: 2},
        {value: 'yellow',  label: 'Yellow', id: 3}
    ];

//setting it here works just fine
$scope.colorModel = $scope.colorOptions[2];


$scope.nextOption = function(){
      $scope.groupIndex++;
      $scope.currentOption = userOptions[$scope.groupIndex];
      $scope.colorModel = $scope.colorOptions[$scope.currentOption.colorID];
      //I event tried this with no luck
      $scope['colorModel'] = $scope.currentOption.colorID;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that what you want to have in `$scope.colorModel` is the color object of the Array `$scope.colorOptions`, but what you want to display in the `select` is the `label`, correct? Then, the correct syntax for `ng-options` would be:

```
<select 
         ng-model="colorModel" 
         ng-change="updateColor(colorModel.id)" 
         ng-options="i as i.label for i in colorOptions">
</select>
```

In the controller do this:

```
app.controller("yourController", function($scope, $filter){
    $scope.colorOptions = [
            {value: 'red', label: 'Red', id: 0},
            {value: 'green', label: 'Green', id: 1},
            {value: 'blue', label: 'Blue', id: 2},
            {value: 'yellow',  label: 'Yellow', id: 3}
        ];
    
    //setting it here works just fine
    $scope.colorModel = $scope.colorOptions[2];
    
    $scope.nextOption = function(){
          $scope.groupIndex++;
          $scope.currentOption = userOptions[$scope.groupIndex];
          $scope.colorModel = $filter('filter')($scope.colorOptions, {id:$scope.currentOption.colorID})[0];
    }
});
```

Notice that you will need to inject the `$filter` service in your `controller`, like this: `app.controller("yourController", function($scope, $filter){...`

## [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zgLdeg1n/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I changed it to match the ng-options example and still no luck on the select changing.  When logging I can see the colorModel is updating, just the select doesn't to update.

Odd, it only showed the code block originally in your reply.  To answer the question yes, I want to show the label that is associated with the currentObject.ID.  Object side it is being updated no problem, just the select isn't playing nice.

Comment: @Rudy my bad, I missed the other half of the problem, I just updated my answer, please have a look at it and let me know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion again Josep.  I tried it with your example and still no luck.  The one thing that does change is when I set the colorModel = $filter.....   the colorModel comes back as undefined.

Comment: @Rudy what's the value of $scope.currentOption.colorID?

Comment: @Rudy it's very difficult to help you because I don't know what you have in the "userOptions" Array, or what the "updateColor" function does, but please have a look at [this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/zgLdeg1n/)

Comment: thank you so much for that example.  $scope.currentOption.colorID matches up to what it is set by the drop down.  Looking at your working example I have to be missing something because it is generating the result I'm expecting.  I'll do a line by line comparison to see what I'm missing.  Thank you sooo much for your help.  Greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Rudy I'm glad that I was able to help you! Good luck with the debugging process!